# building a dashboard with generic views in django

Tags: django, django-forms, dashboard, django-generic-views

I'm trying to build a dashboard, I have the login/logout part in place but there're a lot of concepts I still don't quite understand. Right in this moment I'm trying to build this:

- I have a dashboard with a list of items (listview). Those Items come from a model I built. In order to see that dashboard you need to be logged in (I already have this "login" functionality in place).
- I need to link each one of those Items to a form where I can update the info of those items (updateview). On submission, I want to display a success message or an error message.
- In the dashboard, I need a button that links to a createview form.

this is an app to allow users to create offers and post them on facebook as a facebook app in their fanpages.

The problem I'm having is I don't understand how I put together the view, the form and the url to show what I want.

Is there something I'm missing? Sorry if this question is too stupid.

I'm using Class Based Views to build this. and this is the code I'm using:

In my model.py:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Offer(models.Model):
    offer_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="offers")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="nombre de la empresa")
    offer_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="titulo de la oferta")
    offer_date_from = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False, editable=True, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="fecha en que inicia la oferta")
    offer_date_to = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False, editable=True, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="fecha en que finaliza la oferta")
    offer_detail = models.TextField(verbose_name="detalles de la oferta")
    offer_terms = models.TextField(verbose_name="terminos de la oferta")
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="esta oferta esta publica")
    from_fanpage = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="nombre del fanpage") #fanpage info
    fanpage_id = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name="fanpage id")
    fanpage_url = models.URLField(verbose_name="fanpage url")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.offer_title
```

In my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import Offer, Consumer

# Login Form

#class LoginForm(forms.Form):
#   username = forms.EmailField()
#   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class OfferForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        exclude = ["offer_owner"]

class ConsumerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Consumer
        # exclude = ["offer_obtained", ""]
```

In my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from forms import *

from django import forms

from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Offer

# forms
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

#view for the login
def login_usr(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print "form is valid"
            # user registration or login
            username,pwd=request.POST.get("username",None),request.POST.get("password")
            if not username or not pwd:
                return HttpResponse("Username or password not present")
            try:
                user=User.objects.get(username=username)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist,ex:
                # print "Creating new user ..."
                print "error ..."
                return HttpResponse("No estas registrado en el sistema, registrate")
                # user=User.objects.create_user(username,username,pwd)
            if user:
                print "Authenticating ..."
                user=authenticate(username=username,password=pwd)
            print "Logging in user"
            login(request,user)
            return redirect("dashboard")

        else:
            print "form is not valid"
            return render_to_response("login.html", {'form':form}, RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response("login.html", {'form':LoginForm()}, RequestContext(request))

def logout_usr(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("login")

#view for the dashboard
@login_required(login_url="/offers/login/")
def dashboard(request, *args, **kwargs):
    offer_list = Offer.objects.all()
    template_name = "dashboard.html"

    context = {
        "offer_list": offer_list
    }

    return render(request, template_name, context)

#view for the dashboard list of offers  
class OfferListView(ListView):
    model = Offer


#view for the dashboard's form detail from the list of offers
class OfferUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Offer
    form_class = OfferForm
    template_name = "offers_update_form.html"


# public view for the offer, this could be in a facebook canvas, or a public website that will be mobile or desktop.
@csrf_exempt
def app_public(request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    offer = Offer.objects.get(pk=pk, published=True)
    template_name = "app_public.html"

    context = {
        "offer" : offer
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

In my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

from offers.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'thesocialbrand.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^thesocialbrand/', include('thesocialbrand.foo.urls')),
    url(r'^dashboard/', OfferListView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^dashboard/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', OfferUpdateView.as_view(), name="edit"),
    # url(r'^dashboard/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', dashboard_offer_detail),
    # url(r'^app/', app_public, name='app'),
    url(r'^app/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', app_public),
    url(r'^login/', login_usr, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_usr, name='logout'),
)
```

In my template:
this is the main view, where I put the list of items

```
{% load url from future %}

<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<h4>Hola {{ user }}</h4>
<a href="/offers/logout/">Logout</a>
<h3>Mis ofertas</h3>
<ul>
    {% for offer in offer_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'edit' offer.pk %}">{{ offer.offer_title }}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no offers yet. Check back soon!</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

this is the view for the updateview of my form. Is the detail of my form after you click on one of the items in the list.

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<h4>Hola {{ user }}</h4>

<form name ="offers_update_form" action="/dashboard/edit/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{offer_form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Edit offer" />
</form>
```

When I finish this I'll write a post in my blog explaining all this stuff I discover. It surely will be useful for other beginners that are in the same situation I am and maybe need to build similar stuff.

Comment: Are you aware of the Django admin? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Hi Lain, yes I'm aware of django admin. I understand that it is intended to admin the site, not to allow estrangers to manipulate the site. Am I wrong?